# Passport google authentication is returning [Function: authenticate] instead of google login page

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I'm trying to use passport to login with google. So here's how I created my files.

Created Passport.js for passport configurations which looks like below,

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth2').Strategy;
const Config = require("../../configs/configs");

passport.serializeUser((user , done) => {
    done(null , user);
})
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID:Config.clientId, // Your Credentials here.
    clientSecret:Config.clientSecret, // Your Credentials here.
    callbackURL:"http://localhost:5041/auth/callback",
    passReqToCallback:true
  },
  function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile);
    return done(null, profile);
  }
));

module.exports = passport;
```

check I'm exporting this passport instance in this file.

Now in controller I'm Importing the passport function for authenticate. Now the requirement is such, I need to redirect user to specific URL from backend and invoke the google login page.

SO my controller functions looks something like this.

to redirect:

```
async registrationWithGoogle() {
    try {
      return this.res.send(`<?xml version='1.0'?> <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>HTML Meta Tag</title><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3; url = ${Config.beRedirectUrlPrefix}${Config.serverPort}${Config.beRedirectUrlSuffix}?mode=${this.req.query.target}'/></head><body><p>Redirecting to another URL</p></body></html>`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      loggerError(
        this.req.url,
        this.req.method,
        this.req.connection.remoteAddress,
        this.req.body,
        this.req.params,
        0,
        error
      );
      this.res.send({ status: 0, message: error });
    }
  }
```

in the same controller I'm creating a function against this `/auth/redirect` route and to authenticate. the code looks something like this;

```
  async validatePassportForGoogle() {
    try {
      const x = await passport.authenticate('google', { scope: [ 'email', 'profile' ] });
      console.log("======2======>", x);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

and as an output of x I'm getting `======2======> [Function: authenticate]` as output, instead of profile details.

Can anyone ple correct me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passport is middleware, so need to call on router level.